# @types/socket.io-redis fails on compile as it can't find Adapter exported by @types/socket.io ... which it is

Tags: typescript, socket.io

So, my presumption here is that something is wrong with my tsconfig or similar.

```
npm run compile     

> engine@1.0.0 compile /Users/[...]/engine
> tsc

node_modules/@types/socket.io-redis/index.d.ts:76:45 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/Users/[...]/node_modules/socket.io/dist/index"' has no exported member 'Adapter'.

76     interface RedisAdapter extends SocketIO.Adapter {
```

However, on inspecting `socket.io/dist/index`, it appears that the Adapter interface is indeed exported on line 835, as part of the `SocketIO` namespace.

I've not used either of these @types packages in TS before, but my project is a pretty standard gts setup:

```
{
  "extends": "./node_modules/gts/tsconfig-google.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "build"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "test/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Cany anbody point out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by uninstalling the @types/socket.io-redis package.